# Не отображаются картинки и шрифты на GitHub Pages

Tags: html, css, github, sass, github-pages

Не отображаются картинки и шрифты на GitHub Pages. Поменял '..' на 1 точку в url() картинках, но всё равно не помогло

[Ссылка на проект](https://github.com/mxnvkv/Colors-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что GitHub строит сайт с помощью Jekyll. А Jekyll считает файлы (и папки) начинающиеся с подчёркивания специальными и не копирует их в результатирующий сайт. Если вы не используете Jekyll (вроде нет), то его [можно отключить](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/). Либо просто переименуйте файлы и папки что бы они не начинались с подчёркивания.